# Retrieving XML as downloadable attachment from MVC Controller action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am rewriting an existing webform to use js libraries instead of using the vendor controls and microsoft ajax tooling (basically, updating the web app to use more contemporary methodologies).

The AS-IS page (webform) uses a button click handler on the server to process the submitted data and return a document containing xml, which document can either then be saved or opened (opening opens it up as another tab in the browser).  This happens asynchronously.

The TO-BE page uses jquery ajax to submit the form to an MVC controller, where virtually the same exact code is executed as in the server-side postback case.  I've verified in the browser that the same data is being returned from the caller, but, after returning it, the user is NOT prompted to save/open - the page just remains as if nothing ever happened.

I will put the code below, but I think I am just missing some key diferrence between the postback and ajax/controller contexts to prompt the browser to recognize the returned data as a separate attachment to be saved.  My problem is that I have looked at and tried so many ad-hoc approaches that I'm not certain what I am doing wrong at this point.

**AS-IS Server Side Handler**
(Abridged, since the SendXml() method is what generates the response)

```
protected void btnXMLButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //generate server side biz objects
    //formattedXml is a string of xml iteratively generated from each selected item that was posted back

    var documentStream = MemStreamMgmt.StringToMemoryStream(formattedXml);
    byte[] _documentXMLFile = documentStream.ToArray();

    SendXml(_documentXMLFile);
}

private void SendXml(byte[] xmlDoc)
{
    string _xmlDocument = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlDoc);

    XDocument _xdoc = XDocument.Parse(_xmlDocument);
    var _dcpXMLSchema = new XmlSchemaSet();
    _dcpXMLSchema.Add("", Server.MapPath(@"~/Orders/DCP.xsd"));
    bool _result = true;
    try
    {
        _xdoc.Validate(_dcpXMLSchema, null);
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaValidationException)
    {
        //validation failed raise error
        _result = false;
    }
    // return error message
    if (!_result)
    {
        //stuff to display message
        return;
    }

    // all is well .. download xml file
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" +   "XMLOrdersExported_" + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.xml", DateTime.Now));
    Response.BinaryWrite(xmlDoc);
    Response.Flush();
    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    Response.End();
}
```

**TO-BE (Using jquery to submit to a controller action)**
Client code: button click handler:

```
queueModel.getXmlForSelectedOrders = function () {
    //create form to submit
    $('body').append('<form id="formXmlTest"></form>');

    //submit handler
    $('#formXmlTest').submit(function(event) {
        var orderNbrs = queueModel.selectedItems().map(function (e) { return e.OrderId() });
        console.log(orderNbrs);
        var ordersForXml = orderNbrs;
        var urlx = "http://localhost:1234/svc/OrderServices/GetXml";
        $.ajax({
            url: urlx,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { orders: ordersForXml },
            dataType: "xml",
            accepts: {
                xml: 'application/xhtml+xml',
                text: 'text/plain'
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
              /*Updated per comments */
            console.log(data);

            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.target = "blank";
            link.download = "someFile";//data.name
            console.log(link.download);
            link.href = "http://localhost:23968/svc/OrderServices/GetFile/demo.xml";//data.uri;
            link.click();
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#formXmlTest').submit();
};

//Updated per comments
/* 
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public void GetXml([FromBody] string[] orders)
{
    //same code to generate xml string
    var documentStream = MemStreamMgmt.StringToMemoryStream(formattedXml);
    byte[] _documentXMLFile = documentStream.ToArray();

    //SendXml(_documentXMLFile);
    string _xmlDocument = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_documentXMLFile);

    XDocument _xdoc = XDocument.Parse(_xmlDocument);
    var _dcpXMLSchema = new XmlSchemaSet();
    _dcpXMLSchema.Add("", Server.MapPath(@"~/Orders/DCP.xsd"));
    bool _result = true;
    try
    {
        _xdoc.Validate(_dcpXMLSchema, null);
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaValidationException)
    {
        //validation failed raise error
        _result = false;
    }

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "XMLOrdersExported_" + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.xml", DateTime.Now));
    Response.BinaryWrite(_documentXMLFile);
    Response.Flush();
    //Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    Response.End();
    }
}*/
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public FileResult GetXmlAsFile([FromBody] string[] orders)
{
    var schema = Server.MapPath(@"~/Orders/DCP.xsd");
    var formattedXml = OrderXmlFormatter.GenerateXmlForSelectedOrders(orders, schema);
    var _result = validateXml(formattedXml.DocumentXmlFile, schema);

    // return error message
    if (!_result)
    {
        const string message = "The XML File(s) are not valid! Please check with your administrator!.";
        return null;
    }
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "blargoWargo.xml",
        Inline = false
    };
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/temp/demo.xml"),formattedXml.DocumentXmlFile);
    return File(formattedXml.DocumentXmlFile,MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain,"blarg.xml");
}

[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public FileResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        // for example foo.bak
        FileName = fileName,
        Inline = false
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    var fName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)?fileName:"demo.xml";
    var fArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + fName));
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + fName));
    return File(fArray, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

UPDATE:
I just put the AS-IS/TO-BE side by side, and in the dev tools verified the ONLY difference (at least as far as dev tools shows) is that the ACCEPT: header for TO-BE is:

**application/xhtml+xml, */*; q=0.01**

Whereas the header for AS-IS is

**text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */***

**Update II**
I've found a workaround using a 2-step process with a hyperlink.  It is a mutt of a solution, but as I suspected, apparently when making an ajax call (at least a jQuery ajax call, as opposed to a straight XmlHttpRequest) it is impossible to trigger the open/save dialog.  So, in the POST step, I create and save the desired file, then in the GET step (using a dynamically-created link) I send the file to the client and delete it from the server.  I'm leaving this unanswered for now in the hopes someone who understands the difference deeply can explain why you can't retrieve the file in the course of a normal ajax call.

Comment: The code for MVC action does not make much sense as it does not return result. It is unclear where did you find such example for MVC file download - consider linking to place where you took it from. Not sure what searches you've used but https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+asp.net+mvc+download+xml does not give anything close.

Comment: It's my own code, there is no link to post.  It doesn't return an ActionMethod, it manipulates the response stream, and the results are passed over the wire, so the issue is not that it doesn't return anything.  It may not be returning it *correctly* for my purposes, but it's returning something.

Comment: Do not manipulate the response, just return a FileResult and set the properties correctly for your file using the File method on your controller.

Comment: @Cat_Clan That's partially why I am asking this question.  I tried using file result w.no luck earlier.  Based on your input, I just created a new action, and I'm getting the same response body, and result.  Perhaps I'm setting the file wrong, but, this is what I returned:
return File(formattedXml.DocumentXmlFile,"text/plain","blarg.xml");

Comment: Should be text/xml on second parameter, to return an XML and be parsed as XML by the browser.